# How to specify a dynamic image in Tailwind style class?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, background-image, tailwind-in-js

I am using tailwind. When hovering the mouse over an element, this element should display: dimming the background. At the same time, I want to use a dynamic link to the image so that in the group of elements each one has a different image.

Now in the code the pictures are specified through the style attribute and the mapping of the pictures works, but the dimming does not work, when hovering with the mouse, just another color appears that completely covers the picture.

app.jsx:

```
import data from '../data/data';

...


{data.map((item, index) => (
            <div
              key={index}
              style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${item.image})` }}
              className='shadow-lg shadow-[#dcdcdc] group container rounded-md flex justify-center text-center items-center mx-auto content-div px-2 py-5'
            >
              {/* hover effects for images */}
              <div className='opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-50 transition'>
                <span className='text-xl font bold text-white tracking-wider'>{item.name}</span>
                <div className='text-center'>
                  ...
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
))}
```

index.css:

```
.content-div {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  max-height: 150px;
}

.content-div:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    rgb(127, 29, 29, 0.2),
    rgba(178, 178, 178, 0.7)
  ) !important;
}
```

Comment: The reason is because you are setting the background image and then on hover you are setting the background image as a gradient so you are completely replacing the original image. If you apply the hover gradient to a child element you can get the overlay effect. https://play.tailwindcss.com/hpJCSkRtXF